# ¿Como comparar una variable con un string en Shell Script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Estoy intentando comparar una variable con un String pero no he encontrado la manera de poder hacerlo, la variable es el resultado de una funcion, el cual el resultado puede ser "Terminal" o "Servidor", la cual puedo imprimir sin ningun problema, el problema es que no encuentro la manera de compararla con un string, aqui mi codigo:

```
function seleccionar(){
osascript <<EOT
set rTipo to the button returned of (display dialog "$1" buttons {"Terminal", "Servidor"} default button "Servidor")
if(rTipo = "Terminal")then
return rTipo
do shell script "echo 'type=terminal'> ~/Desktop/type.txt"
end if
if(rTipo = "Servidor")then
return rTipo
do shell script "echo 'type=servidor'> ~/Desktop/type.txt"
end if
EOT
}

value="$(seleccionar 'Selecciona el tipo de instalacion:')"
echo $value
```

Busco compararla de esta manera:

```
if value == "Servidor ; then
  if lsof -Pi :3306 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then #comprueba el puerto 3306
  echo "El puerto 3306 ya se encuentra en uso"
  exit 1
  fi
fi
```

existe alguna manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la manera de hacerlo, aqui un ejemplo:

```
if [[ $value = "Terminal" ]];
then
echo "Seleccionaste Terminal"
elif [[ $value = "Servidor" ]];
then
echo "Seleccionaste Servidor"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar tu propia respuesta a tu pregunta.

Además de [[ puede usar test o [
Por ejemplo, para comparar un string, como lo hiciste con `[[ "$value" = "Terminal" ]]` podrías hacerlo de la misma manera con:

```
$ [ "$value" = "Terminal" ] && echo "es igual" || echo "es diferente"
$ # o con test
$ test "$value" = "Terminal" && echo "es igual" || echo "es diferente"
```

`test`y `[` son sinónimos de los comandos propios de bash.
En cambio `[[` es una versión actualizada de [ , sin embargo, no es portable.

Para más información sobre esos comandos, puedes consultar los siguientes enlaces.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs

Comment: Gracias por la informacion

Answer (score 0):

A mi, en ubuntu 20 me funciona lo siguiente:

```
if [ "$value" = "Terminal" ] 
then
echo "Seleccionaste Terminal"
elif [ "$value" = "Servidor" ]
then
echo "Seleccionaste Servidor"
fi
```

Comment: ¿En que se diferencia tu respuesta de la ya dada por el usuario **AngelMontesDeOca**?